# Finding probability that a car experiences a failure

Tags: probability

> A car is new at the beginning of a calendar year. The time, in years,
> before the car experiences its first failure is exponentially
> distributed with mean 2. Calculate the probability that the car
> experiences its first failure in the last quarter of some calendar
> year.

#### Attempt

Let $T$ be rv in years before the car experiences its first failure. We know $T$ is $exp(\lambda = 1/2) $. We want to find

$$ P( 1 > T > 3/4) = F(1) - F(3/4) = e^{-3/4} - e^{-1/2} \approx 0.0808$$

but the answer in the book of my books gives $\boxed{0.205}$. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just misread the question, it means the first failure in the last quarter of some calendar year, it need not be the first year.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P\left(n+1 > T > n + \frac34\right) &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(F(n+1)-F\left(n+\frac34\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\exp \left(-\frac{n+\frac34}2 \right) - \exp\left( -\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \right)\\
&= \left( \exp\left(-\frac38 \right) -\exp\left( -\frac12\right)\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-n/2) \\
&=\frac{\left( \exp\left(-\frac38 \right) -\exp\left( -\frac12\right)\right)}{1-\exp(-1/2)} \\
&\approx 0.205
\end{align}

Comment: can you explain what theorem/equation allowed you to change the summation to 1-exp(-1/2) in denominator?

Comment: That is a geometric series with common ratio $\exp(-\frac12)$.

Comment: yep.. I misread that problem.  sneaky bastards put .081 as an answer for dummies like me.. thank you Siong Thye Goh

Answer (score 0):

You need to find this:$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-{1\over2}(k-0.25)} -e^{-{1\over2}k} $$

because you're looking for the probability that the car experiences a failure in any year, not just the first year. The summation above will give you the answer in your textbook.